# Why is the string literal not moved?

Tags: rust, ownership

I was going through [Rust second edition ebook](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch08-02-strings.html) and in a piece of code from the linked chapter, if I remove the reference operator (`&`) in line 3, the program still works perfectly fine.

```
let mut s1 = String::from("foo");
let s2 = "bar";
s1.push_str(&s2); // here
println!("s2 is {}", s2);
```

The value of `s2` should be moved as per the book. However, if I change

```
s1.push_str(&s2);
```

to

```
s1.push_str(s2);
```

the following line should trigger an error, but it doesn't happen:

```
println!("s2 is {}", s2);
```

A fragment from the documentation:

> Listing 8-16: Using a string slice after appending its contents to a
>   String
>   *If the push_str method took ownership of s2 , we wouldn’t be able to print out its value on the last line. However, this code works as we’d
>   expect!*

I am using Rust 1.24.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of `push_str` is:

```
pub fn push_str(&mut self, string: &str)
```

Which means its argument is a reference. This matches the type of `s2`, which is a reference to a static string slice:

```
let s2: &'static str = "bar";
```

The compiler is able to dereference the argument of `push_str` as much as necessary, so `s1.push_str(s2)` works just as well as `s1.push_str(&&&&&s2)`.

Since in the end you are always passing a reference, the argument is not moved (only borrowed), and `s2` is still available after it is pushed.

Comment: The actual important part is that `&str: Copy`, like all immutable references.